# Running protractor e2e tests in multiple versions of IE

Tags: internet-explorer, protractor

Is there a best practice for running protractor e2e tests in multiple versions of Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote a blog post about how to get setup with protractor and IE VMs:

http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/

The article is a bit extensive because it targets my colleagues, so you should look into below section first, maybe you'll find there what you're looking for:

#### Alternative 1 - Install nodejs on Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use [saucelabs](https://saucelabs.com/). One of the best practices everywhere is to delegate task to professionals. saucelabs provides many versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to make your system easily maintained, resilient to crashes and shutdowns, and fully automated. I'm setting up a system to run multiple Windows and IE configs to test against. I used:

- http://www.ubuntu.com Ubuntu, for the Host OS
- https://www.virtualbox.org Virtualbox, for running multiple Windows and IE instances
- http://modern.ie for the VM images
- http://gruntjs.com Grunt, for task automation
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-protractor-runner Grunt plugin, for Protractor
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent Grunt plug, for concurrency
- http://jenkins-ci.org/ Jenkins, for build automation on Git commits

Whenever a Git commit happens, Jenkins starts a build, which then runs a script to check and ensure the needed VM images are running, and that Selenium is running, then it runs the grunt task, which fires off multiple simultaneous ie instances for testing.